How to join 3 tables in postgres sql?
I was solving Danny Ma's Pizza Runner SQL Case study. In one of the sections Pricing and Ratings, I got stuck in 2 questions and I'm unable to arrive at the right solution.
Link to the case study: https://8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-2/
[cleaned_customer_orders table](https://i.sstatic.net/fEgXb.png)
[cleaned_runner_orders table](https://i.sstatic.net/sl6kd.png)
[extras table](https://i.sstatic.net/Ggm0B.png)

CREATE TABLE customer_orders (  
  "order_id" INTEGER,  
  "customer_id" INTEGER,  
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,    
  "exclusions" VARCHAR(4),  
  "extras" VARCHAR(4),  
  "order_time" TIMESTAMP  
);  

INSERT INTO customer_orders  
  ("order_id", "customer_id", "pizza_id", "exclusions", "extras", "order_time")  
VALUES  
  ('1', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 18:05:02'),  
  ('2', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 19:00:52'),  
  ('3', '102', '1', '', '', '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),  
  ('3', '102', '2', '', NULL, '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),  
  ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),  
  ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),  
  ('4', '103', '2', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),  
  ('5', '104', '1', 'null', '1', '2020-01-08 21:00:29'),  
  ('6', '101', '2', 'null', 'null', '2020-01-08 21:03:13'),  
  ('7', '105', '2', 'null', '1', '2020-01-08 21:20:29'),  
  ('8', '102', '1', 'null', 'null', '2020-01-09 23:54:33'),  
  ('9', '103', '1', '4', '1, 5', '2020-01-10 11:22:59'),  
  ('10', '104', '1', 'null', 'null', '2020-01-11 18:34:49'),  
  ('10', '104', '1', '2, 6', '1, 4', '2020-01-11 18:34:49');  


CREATE TABLE runner_orders (
  "order_id" INTEGER,
  "runner_id" INTEGER,
  "pickup_time" VARCHAR(19),
  "distance" VARCHAR(7),
  "duration" VARCHAR(10),
  "cancellation" VARCHAR(23)
);

INSERT INTO runner_orders
  ("order_id", "runner_id", "pickup_time", "distance", "duration", "cancellation")
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2020-01-01 18:15:34', '20km', '32 minutes', ''),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-01 19:10:54', '20km', '27 minutes', ''),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-03 00:12:37', '13.4km', '20 mins', NULL),
  ('4', '2', '2020-01-04 13:53:03', '23.4', '40', NULL),
  ('5', '3', '2020-01-08 21:10:57', '10', '15', NULL),
  ('6', '3', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Restaurant Cancellation'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-08 21:30:45', '25km', '25mins', 'null'),
  ('8', '2', '2020-01-10 00:15:02', '23.4 km', '15 minute', 'null'),
  ('9', '2', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'Customer Cancellation'),
  ('10', '1', '2020-01-11 18:50:20', '10km', '10minutes', 'null');

select order_id, customer_id, pizza_id,
    case
        when exclusions in ('null', '') then null
        else exclusions
    end as exclusions,
    case 
        when extras in ('null', '') then null
        else extras
    end as extras,
    order_time
into cleaned_customer_orders
from customer_orders

select 
    order_id,
    runner_id,
    cast(case 
        when pickup_time = 'null' then null
        else pickup_time
    end as timestamp) as pickup_time,
    cast(case 
        when distance = 'null' then null
        else trim('km' from distance)
    end as float) as distance,
    cast(case
        when duration = 'null' then null
        else substring(duration, 1, 2)
    end as int)as duration,
    case
        when cancellation in ('null', '') then null
        else cancellation
end as cancellation
into cleaned_runner_orders
from runner_orders;

select * from cleaned_customer_orders
select * from cleaned_runner_orders

alter table cleaned_customer_orders
add column record_id serial;

select * from cleaned_customer_orders;

-- to generate extras table
select      
    cco.record_id,
    trim(e.value) as topping_id
into extras
from 
    cleaned_customer_orders as cco
    cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(cco.extras, ',')) as e(value);

Q1. Query
select   
    sum(case when cco.pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as pizza_cost  
from cleaned_customer_orders cco  
join pizza_names pn on pn.pizza_id = cco.pizza_id  
join cleaned_runner_orders cro on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
where cro.cancellation is null  

Q2. Query
with cte_extras_cost as (select  
    sum(case when pn.pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as pizza_cost,  
    count (e.topping_id)*1 as extras_cost  
    from cleaned_customer_orders cco  
    join pizza_names pn on pn.pizza_id = cco.pizza_id  
    left join extras e on e.record_id = cco.record_id  
    join cleaned_runner_orders cro on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
    where cro.cancellation is null)  
select pizza_cost, coalesce(extras_cost, 0) as extras_cost, (pizza_cost+coalesce(extras_cost, 0))  
 as total_cost  
from cte_extras_cost;  

Q5. Query
with cte as (  
    select   
    sum(cro.distance*0.30) as delivery_cost,  
    sum(case when cco.pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as total_cost  
from cleaned_runner_orders cro  
join cleaned_customer_orders cco on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
where cro.cancellation is null)  
select cte.total_cost, cte.delivery_cost, (cte.total_cost - cte.delivery_cost) as actual_cost  
from cte  

My output:
Q1. 138
Q2. pizza_cost=150, extras_cost=4, total_cost=154
Q5. total_cost=138, delivery_cost=64, actual_cost=73
The correct answers are
Q1. 138
Q2. pizza_cost=138, extras_cost=4, total_cost=142
Q5. total_cost=138, delivery_cost=43, actual_cost=94

What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share all details in text form

Above are the images, where I have shown what tables I'm using to get the output and what queries I have written. I'm getting the output but its not right for Q2 and Q5 and I'm not understanding why is it happening?

Please also share sample data and the table structure

I can't share images directly as it requires to complete 10 reputations. If you open the link given for the tables, you can see the table structure and the contents clearly.

You don't need to share any images. Share all details in text form, like CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements

I have added the code for the tables how they are created and values are inserted.

it's better if you post insert statements to fill temp tables
q1
select   
    sum(case when cco.pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as pizza_cost  
from customer_orders cco  
left join runner_orders cro on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
where coalesce(cro.cancellation,'') not in ('Restaurant Cancellation', 'Customer Cancellation')

q2
with 
cco as 
(select *, row_number() over(order by order_id, pizza_id) as rn from customer_orders)
, ex as (
select rn, case when extras = 'null' then null else extras end as extras from 
            cco
            where coalesce(case when extras = 'null' then null else extras end,'') <> ''
)
, ex1 as (
select trim(unnest(string_to_array(extras, ',')))::int as topping_id, rn from ex
)
, extras as (
select count(topping_id) as topping_cnt, rn from ex1 group by rn
)
, cte_extras_cost as (
    select 
    sum(case when pn.pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) pizza_cost
    , sum(topping_cnt*1) as extras_cost
    from cco  
    join pizza_names pn on pn.pizza_id = cco.pizza_id  
    left join extras e on e.rn = cco.rn  
    join runner_orders cro on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
    where coalesce(cro.cancellation,'') not in ('Restaurant Cancellation', 'Customer Cancellation')
)  
select pizza_cost, coalesce(extras_cost, 0) as extras_cost, (pizza_cost+coalesce(extras_cost, 0))  
 as total_cost  
from cte_extras_cost;

q5
with 
cro as 
(
    select 
        case when distance <> '' then cast(distance as numeric) else 0 end as distance, order_id, runner_id, 
        pickup_time, duration, cancellation 
    from (
    SELECT order_id, runner_id, pickup_time, replace(replace(distance, 'km', ''), 'null', '') as distance, 
    duration, cancellation 
    from 
    pizza_runner.runner_orders
    ) q1
)
, cco as (
select sum(case when pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as pizza_cost, order_id
from customer_orders
group by order_id 
)
, cte as (  
    select   
    sum(cro.distance*0.30) as delivery_cost, 
    sum(pizza_cost) as total_cost
from cro  
join cco on cro.order_id = cco.order_id  
where coalesce(cro.cancellation,'') not in ('Restaurant Cancellation', 'Customer Cancellation')
)  
select 
cte.total_cost, cte.delivery_cost, (cte.total_cost - cte.delivery_cost) as actual_cost  
from cte

q1 and q2 have clear decision,
BUT I can't find how it's possible to get 45 for delivery cost from that numbers in Q5
distance count

yes, you're right its not 45 but 43, thank you for your solution. But can you tell what is wrong with my code?

q2. When you join orders and extras you have to use group by and count before join. In your case you multiply pizza cost with extras number

q5. you have to use one-to-one relationship when you join orders, but in customers orders there more than one row per order. Than is why i use construction with group by:  select sum(case when pizza_id = 1 then 12 else 10 end) as pizza_cost, order_id
from customer_orders
group by order_id

In steps before last step i tried to get a table like yours cleaned_customer_orders and cleaned_runner_orders, if you execute select of every step of WITH clause you can understand it
